# why is the hot water coming into the washing machine coming in so slowly?

Tags: plumbing

The hot water that is coming into the washing machine is coming in very slowly.  I checked the screen in the hose connection and it was cleared.  What could the problem be?

Comment: Did you try pulling the hose off of the washer and see how fast it flows from there (in a sink, of course)? It would tell you if there is a blockage before the hose or there is an issue in the washer itself.

Comment: thanks, why didn't I think of that?